# Compiling the same program on different systems produces different results?

Tags: c, date, gcc, printf

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DATE_SIZE   10

// Declare global variables.
char *program_name = NULL;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
// Declare variables.
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
    char date[DATE_SIZE + 1] = {0};

// Store today's date in a string for comparison.
    if(sprintf(date, "%d/%d/%d", tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_year - 100) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: main error: sprintf failed.\n", program_name);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

// Print date to user.
    printf("Date: %s\n", date);

// Exit gracefully.
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Which is compiled with the following:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -O3 -o program program.c
```

I also have 2 machines both running **Arch linux**:

> Linux laptop 4.15.7-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 28 19:01:57 UTC 2018
>   x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> Linux storage 4.14.66-1-ARCH #1 SMP Sat Aug 25 01:09:50 UTC 2018
>   armv6l GNU/Linux

When I compile on my laptop, it's clean and it runs perfectly.  When I compile on my storage server, I get the following error:

```
program.c: In function 'main':
program.c:20:5: error: '/' directive writing 1 byte into a region of size between 0 and 10 [-Werror=format-overflow=]
  if(sprintf(date, "%d/%d/%d", tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_year - 100) < 0)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
program.c:20:5: note: directive argument in the range [-2147483648, 2147483547]
program.c:20:5: note: 'sprintf' output between 6 and 36 bytes into a destination of size 11
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Why is there a difference?

UPDATE

---

All the comments seem to be dealing with how to fix the error.  First off, you need to know that this is a minimized program.  The date I create is compared to another that I didn't create.  Hence the mm/dd/yy format.  Also, most functions that the include an 'n' in the name (strncpy, snprintf...) are for when you don't know the data or it is user generated.  I look at it as lazy programming, because you are not aware of the data you are working with.  Also, I know for a fact this program won't be used in 82 years.

No, my question has to deal with the difference in compilation results.

Comment: It is just warning you that `"%d/%d/%d"` could contain more than 11 bytes and therefore could overflow.

Comment: What  happens when `tm.tm_year == INT_MAX`?

Comment: Probably difference in the range of values represented by `int` changing the number of bytes it may take to fit your printed ints?

Comment: As Osiris said; also it's advised to use `snprintf()` :-)

Comment: I dont think there is a printf specifier for max width (there could be, I just don't know about it) but a %d can print width up to INT_MAX which is a 10 digit number on common arches...

Comment: Use snprintf, and "%2d", then there's no reason for the compiler to warn you.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker `"%2d"` vs `"%d"` does not help. 2 is a minimum width.

Comment: Chux is right, %2d won't fix the issue, but it might give a hint to the compiler to make it suppress the warning. I don't know--seems like a pretty extreme warning in the first place.

Comment: Hmm, on second thought, even a system with 16-bit `int` types would have no problem overflowing the buffer.  Curious why it only warns on one system.  Different versions of GCC?

Comment: %d/%d/%d (month/day/year) is rarely a good representation for a date. Try to use YYYY-MM-DD per ISO 8601. Also see https://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: If your question is about the difference in compilation results, please include the compiler versions (`gcc -v`).

Comment: You have complained about the three answers which have suggested ways to fix potential problems in your code.  One out of two compilers has chosen to warn you about some of the very same potential problems.  The other compiler has not.  Why are they different?  Because different compilers are different.  Why do you care?  Do you suspect that your code is right, that the compiler that did not warn is right not to warn, and that the compiler that did warn, and the answers here that warned, are all wrong, or what?

Answer (score 0):

As Osiris said, `sprintf()` may write more than `DATE_SIZE+1` bytes into `date`.

If you want to store a filename, I suggest using [`FILENAME_MAX`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/FILENAME_MAX/) for the size of the buffer -- it's guaranteed to be *big enough*.

Also, use `snprintf()` to limit the amount of characters written in the buffer. This avoids memory management issues, which in other cases may lead to security vulnerabilities.

Check the return value of `snprintf()` and confirm the whole string has been written (i.e. your `date` was big enough.

```
char date[FILENAME_MAX];
int rv = sprintf(date, sizeof(date), "%d/%d/%d",
                 tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_year - 100);
if (rv < 0) printf("encoding error\n");
if (rv == sizeof(date)) printf("not big enough\n");
```

Comment: For some braindead reason I thought this was the name of a file >_>

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd compiler is your friend.

It has properly warned

> 'sprintf' output between 6 and 36 bytes into a destination of size 11

If `tm.tm_year` is a large value, the buffer will overflow.

There is little gained with coding such a scant buffer size of 11.

---

An `int` can take up to `ceil(log10(INT_MAX))` digits.  Together with a sign, that is no more than:

```
//                   sign v--- value bits -------v *log10(2)  round
#define INT_DEC_LEN (1 + (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT - 1)*302/100 + 1)
```

Consider a buffer large enough, no matter the contents of `struct tm tm`.  What is a few extra bytes between friends?

```
struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
#define DMY_FMT "%d/%d/%d"
#define DMY_SIZE (sizeof(DMY_FMT) + 3*INT_DEC_LEN + 1)

char date[DMY_SIZE] = {0};

if(sprintf(date, "%d/%d/%d", tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_year - 100) < 0)
```

---

Code can go the `snprintf()` route too.  Note a negative or large return value indicates a problem.

```
int cnt = snprintf(date, sizeof data, "%d/%d/%d", tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_year - 100);
if (cnt < 0 || cnt >= sizeof data) {
  // Handle error
}
```

---

Following [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is a good idea for dates. [@jarmod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066849/compiling-the-same-program-on-different-systems-produces-different-results/52067034#comment91084363_52066849)

Needs something like

```
"%04d-%02d-%02d", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday);
```

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. That definition `#define DATE_SIZE 10` is way too small.  Just make it 100.  Memory is cheap these days, and life's too short to spend time trying to decide whether 10 is big enough or maybe you need 11, and then chasing bugs after you wrongly choose 10 but it turns out it really did need to be 11 after all.
2. Don't call `sprintf`.  Call `snprintf(date, sizeof(date), ...)` (or `snprintf(date, DATE_SIZE, ...)`) instead. That way you definitively won't overflow your `date` array.  (In your code, you checked the return value from `sprintf` as if to catch that sort of error, but plain `sprintf` does *not* catch that sort of error.)
3. Please don't compute `tm.tm_year - 100`.  It'll work today, but it wouldn't have worked 18 years ago, and it won't work 82 years from now, and that may not sound like a big deal, but it's still wrong.  If you can get away with it, please compute and print `tm.tm_year + 1900`.  If you simply *must* print an old-fashioned pre-Y2K two-digit year, you can use `tm.tm_year % 100`.